# Long delay using mysqli in PHP script

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm running Apache on Cent OS, and I've installed mysqli for PHP using the command:

```
yum install php-pdo php-mysqli
```

Unfortunately, any PHP script using mysqli is exceedingly slow.  Once the http request is made, the response is consistently sent back 8 seconds later.  For example, if all I have in my script is the following:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("myServer", "myUsername", "myPassword", "myDb");
```

then the response will come back 8 seconds later. When I perform database operations like SELECT, the speed is the same. Looks like establishing the connection to mysql is the bottleneck although mysql is running on the same server as Apache.

Any ideas on how I could reduce the response time?

EDIT:

I finally isolated the problem to using my server's name (eg., 'myserver.net') instead of 'localhost'.  Switching to localhost made the connection/login execute very quickly.  Thanks for the ideas on how to trouble-shoot!

Comment: check the logs, this is like marvel reading otherwise...

Comment: Is it the same if you try to connect with PDO or the regular mysql driver? How fast is the connection through the console mysql client?

Comment: I am not sure if this makes any difference at all but did you try with IP address rather than `localhost` say `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: +1 for solving it yourself!